# How to keep the size of images and table's cells relative on browser resizing

Tags: javascript, css, resize, html

I have board game with some image and table.
The display is ok when I am working with Chrome but on other browsers, such IE, or other computer with smaller screen then mine the display is being disrupted.
When I tried to resize my browser I found this problem too.

**Before resizing browser to left:**
[image]

**After resizing browser to left:**
[image]

I found posts on this issue and they suggested to use:

```
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
```

to the pictures but it didn't help.

**CSS:**

```
td {
    width: 105px;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
table
{
    position: fixed;
    left:9px;
    top:8px;
}

#dice
{
   right: 230px;
    position:fixed; 
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<img id="dice" src="Resources/images/dice_5.png" number="5">
<table oncontextmenu="return false">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="" cellnumber="1" row="0" col="0"><span>1</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="2" row="0" col="1"><span>2</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="3" row="0" col="2"><span>3</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="4" row="0" col="3"><span>4</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="5" row="0" col="4"><span>5</span></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you want to keep the dice in that spot then try putting it in its own `<td>` and then
On the `#dice` take out the `position:fixed;`
Or make it `position: absolute;`
The dice is setting 230px from browsers border.

Comment: And another pilgrim embarks on the long journey to find responsiveness.

Comment: Maybe set up a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `position: fixed;` which takes the `table` and `img` out of the document flow and displays them in the same place on the screen even if you scroll down the page; this means that they are not aware of the space that either of them occupies.

If you don't need the elements to be `fixed` I would suggest rearranging their order in HTML and floating them instead:

```css
table {
    float: left;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 90px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;    
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 105px;
}
#dice {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<table oncontextmenu="return false">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="" cellnumber="1" row="0" col="0"><span>1</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="2" row="0" col="1"><span>2</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="3" row="0" col="2"><span>3</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="4" row="0" col="3"><span>4</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="5" row="0" col="4"><span>5</span></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<img id="dice" src="data:image/png;base64,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" number="5" />
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/LqwbLwv3/

If it is required to keep them `fixed` and the table is a set width (which seems to be the case) you can position the `img` from the `left` instead, that way it will not attempt to occupy the same space as the `table`:

```css
table {
    left:9px;
    position: fixed;
    top:8px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 90px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 105px;
}
#dice {
   left: 570px;
   position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<img id="dice" src="data:image/png;base64,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" number="5" />
<table oncontextmenu="return false">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="" cellnumber="1" row="0" col="0"><span>1</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="2" row="0" col="1"><span>2</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="3" row="0" col="2"><span>3</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="4" row="0" col="3"><span>4</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="5" row="0" col="4"><span>5</span></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jw8buh20/